# HTML CSS - Footer - Space underneath

Tags: html, css

Am having issues trying to get my footer to 'stick' to the bottom of the page below all of the content. I've tried many different techniques but can't get it to work with the header.

What is the best way to style my layout to achieve this?

As you can see the sidebar & content divs go through the footer.

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>


    <header>
        <div id="title_wrapper">
                <h1 id="title_text">Title</h1>
                <p>title</p>
        </div>
    </header>

   <div id="wrapper">

       <div id="content">

            <p>Languages</p>

            <ul>
                 <li>1</li>
                 <li>2</li>
                 <li>3</li>
                 <li>4</li>
                 <li>5</li>

            </ul>

             <p>Frameworks</p>

            <ul>
                 <li>1</li>
                 <li>2</li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">

              Sidebar  
        </div>
    </div>

   <footer>
       Footer

   </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}



h1, p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}


/*Content*/

#wrapper{

  min-height: 70%;
 height: auto;
 height: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto -400px;
}

#content{
float:left;
width:70%;
height: 100%;

}

#sidebar{
padding-top: 30px;
float:left;
width: 30%;
background-color: lightgrey;
height: 100%;
text-align: center
}

/* Header */

header #title_text{

 font-size: 70px;
}

header #title_wrapper{
text-align:center;
position: relative;
top:100px;

}

header {

background-color: orange;
position: relative;
height:30%;
width: 100%;
color:white;
margin:0;

}


/* footer */
footer{
background-color: #202020;
color: white;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
bottom: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, please do a google search for "sticky footer" - there's a lot of different ways this can be achieved

Comment: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zqmpLenp/

Comment: Check my answer for the jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/pdyrgc2j/1/). Remove the trailing 1/ to see Declan's original code but, with position: absolute changed to position: fixed (https://jsfiddle.net/pdyrgc2j/)

Comment: Make that https://jsfiddle.net/pdyrgc2j/3/

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This marks the question closed and helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some weird work arounds that I couldn't understand.

I put your code into a jsfiddle and fixed the problems. This is how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/pdyrgc2j/3/

The changes are:

1. Removed `margin: 0 auto -400px;` on the wrapper. Why did you need that?
2. Removed the `top: 100px` from `#title-wrapper`. Again couldn't understand why you needed that?
3. **The main problem causing the scrolling of sidebar was the `30px` padding on sidebar.** Solved that by moving the text into another div inside the sidebar and applying padding to that div
4. <strike>Changing position to fixed for the footer is advisable as suggested by @Pankaj, but after the above changes, you won't notice any difference</strike>

**EDIT:** Actually, changing position to fixed is **NOT** advisable as the footer will always be visible on screen. Don't set position property at all, as shown in the Fiddle, and the footer will always go below the content.

Comment: thanks that worked! and yea i was experimenting and had redundant code i guess

Comment: i have noticed the sidebar div still overlaps the footer div

Comment: But the footer is still above the sidebar isn't it? Do you want the footer to go below the sidebar?

Comment: @DeclanWatt: Check the answer now. Don't set position property to fixed. If you do, it is removed from normal document flow and even if you keep adding content, the footer is always visible. Now, the footer won't overlap with the sidebar.

Comment: I was confused because it appeared from your code that you wanted it to stay on screen like a floating footer, which is always on screen no matter how much you scroll

Comment: @DeclanWatt: Did removing the position property from CSS work to not overlap the sidebar and footer? Please check and reply.

Comment: A gentle reminder: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This marks the question closed and helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` for footer

```
footer {
    background-color: #202020;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The major problem is the 30px padding on sidebar, that is causing overflow as height is also set to 100%. I solved that as mentioned in my answer.